# One isset within another isset with html and php not working

Tags: php, html, while-loop, isset

Dear Stack Overflow members,

I’m trying to create a form for school awards where a user will select a class (level) and submit. The awards for that class (there can be many awards) will display in a table with a dropdown of a list of students in that class beside each award.

The user will then select a student from the dropdown beside each award and submit again which will save the records in a table.

It is working fine except the last part where the students and the awards are not being saved. Not sure if the issue is with one isset within another isset is causing the issue.

```html
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
 include 'db_connect.php'; 
 $level  = $_POST['level'];
 
  $query =  mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT a.awardcode, a.level, b.awardname, a.year FROM awardyrlevel AS a
  INNER JOIN award AS b
  ON a.awardcode = b.awardcode
  WHERE a.level = '$level' AND a.year = year(curdate())");
 

      ?>
      <table border="1" style= "background-color: white; color: #761a9b; <!--margin: 0 auto-->;" >
    <thead>
   <tr>
     <th>Award Code</th>
     <th>Award Name</th>
     <th>Year Level</th>     
     <th>Select Student</th>    
   </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
   <?php
     while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $query ) ){
?>
    <tr>
      <td> <input type = "text" name="awardcode[]" value = "<?php echo $row['awardcode']; ?>" readonly /> </td>
      <td><?php echo "{$row['awardname']}" ?> </td>
      <td><?php echo "{$row['level']}" ?></td>
     <td><select name="studcode[]" >
        <option disabled selected value> -- Select Student -- </option> 
        <?php
         $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM student where year_level = '$level'");

         while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){
          echo '<option value = " '.$row['stud_code'].'"> '.$row['name'].' </option>';
         }
        ?>
      </select>      
   
     </td>
    </tr>\n;
    
  
   <?php  } ?>
  
    </tbody>
    </table>
   <br><br>
   <input id="save_button" type="submit" name="saveselection" value="Save Selection"> 
   <input id="exit_button" type="submit" name="exit" value="Exit"  onclick="window.history.go(-1); return false;">   
 
<?php
     
 if(isset($_POST['saveselection'])) {

  $awardcode = $_POST['awardcode'];
  $studcode = $_POST['studcode'];
  $level = $row['level'];
  $year = year(curdate());
  $session_user = '2365';
  echo $awardcode;
  
  foreach ($_POST['awardcode'] as $awardcode) {

  $query =  mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO `awardwinner`(`awardcode`, `stud_code`, `level`, `year`, `doe`, `enteredby`) 
       VALUES ('$awardcode', '$studcode', '$level', '$year', now(), '$session_user')");
  }  
 
 }
}
?>
```

The code I have written is simple with html and php. I tried to debug this for quite sometime. Can any of you please suggest what is wrong with this that the records cant be saved?

Comment: Wide open to SQL injection

Comment: `$year = year(curdate());`  `year()` and `curdate()` are not PHP functions

Comment: ... and this is why developers/programmers have spent decades hammering home the idea of [Separation of Concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)

Comment: An important note: Your code is unsafe: When you are using a variable directly in your SQL-query it can easily be hacked. Especially since you are getting it directly from a post variable. So anyone can easily send a post request and delete or modify the data of your database.

[You need to escape them!](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

Comment: Hi Patrick, thanks for pointing out. I have rectified the year function. But even after that it is not inserting records in the table. @ CD001, this is entirely test mode so I have not paid much attention to SQL injection. But thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things wrong with this code, including not keeping to standards of PHP programming. Keep your issets at the top of the page, don't litter them throughout, it makes things difficult to track.

You have an input with the name listed as an array... why? You're not submitting multiple values here. Perhaps you mean to use it as a checkbox/radio? Otherwise it's not needed.

Then in your final query, you're actually using ` for a number of them, instead of ' . That's a ` which should be under your esc key, instead of an apostrophe (')

Also just as a preference, I tend to write for readability rather than raw efficiency when working with a few people, so I personally would write:

```
$query = "WHATEVER MY QUERY IS";
$get_thing_query = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_thing_query)){
//Do your stuff, if you're not expecting multiple rows don't use while.
}
```

Comment: Hi cmprogram, you are correct. There will have multiple awards for students of each class (level) and the teacher/user will select a student from the dropdown menu (which is functioning correctly). I could have added the screenshot to this reply which would have explained it more, but I couldn't find any button to attach a file.